# Angularjs and Html5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am developing a SPA webapp using AngularJS. I am adding a ticker feature in my website, idea is to get warning messages from server that also asynchronously and display those warnings as ticker.

I have taken a ticker dialog box as a different view and loading this view when server sends any warning, since server keeps on sending warning i want that my dialog box which is a view here must dynamically append without removing the older view from screen and so on.

So how can i load a single view multiple times on my main html page dynamically.
please let me know is there a way to do so using AngularJS.
thank u

Comment: Please add some code also ticker URL so as to help you.

Comment: Just want to confirm, ticker means something like [this](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#alerts), If yes, I have an answer for the same.